# How to Arrange JSON Parsed Array Based On Page Number?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, uiscrollview

i am newbie in iOS Development i parsed my JSON Data my Data like as

```
{
mid: "1",
name: "august 2014",
front_image:"http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/magazineimage/frontimage/1.jpg",
title: "August fist edition",
release_date: "2014-08-01",
short_description: "Here we present to you for the first time our Magazine Trueman India. “Trueman India” covers Bollywood Gossips, film reviews, upcoming movies, F",
current_issue: 0,
 -demopage: [
        {
        link:my image URL
        page_no: "1"
        },
        {
        link: my image URL,
        page_no: "16"
        },
        {
        link: my image URL,
        page_no: "2"
        },
        {
        link: my image URL,
        page_no: "22"
        },
        {
        link: my image URL,
        page_no: "25"
        },
        {
         link: my image URL,
         page_no: "26"
         },
```

And i parsed this Data into two array like as

```
NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
     self.imagesa= nil;
    if([jsonDict count]>0)
    {
        NSArray *arrData = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"data"];
        if([arrData count]>0)
        {
            NSDictionary *imgDict = [arrData objectAtIndex:1];
            if([imgDict count]>0)
             {
            NSMutableArray *imgsLinkArray = [imgDict objectForKey:@"demopage"];
            self.imagesa = imgsLinkArray;
              }
        }
    }
```

then it is Parsed and i got aresult what i want but here one problem is taht when i Show this image with Page number in Scrollview then i Show my image in to as per i got JSON data but i want my Imageview are Based on PageNumber like as From 1 to upto the data array Size.please Give me Solution for that i arrange my Image Based on my page number Wise here my Code for image and Page Number Parsing is

```
for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *image=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    NSString *pageNumber=[dict valueForKey:@"page_no"];
    smallImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    pageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    [pageLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     [smallImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    [pageLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page%@",pageNumber]];
```

and i added my label and imageview into my Scrollview then it is Working as i want but it is not Show image Based on Page nuber like as From ! to upto array size please Give me Solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

Sort your `imagesLinkArray` this way:

```
self.imagesa = [[imgsLinkArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
  if ([obj1[@"page_no"] intValue] > [obj2[@"page_no"] intValue]) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
  } else if ([obj1[@"page_no"] intValue] < [obj2[@"page_no"] intValue]) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
  }
  return NSOrderedSame;
}] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: then erro is uncompactible pointer set to 'NSMuttable array'to NSArray.

Comment: Okay... does `self.imagesa` need to be mutable? If so, just use the `mutableCopy` selector on the result of `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`...

Comment: here my self.imegesa is a NSMuttable array.

Comment: So then use `mutableCopy` as I suggested. Or you could create a new `NSMutableArray` with the `arrayWithArray:` constructor. Basic conversion between `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` is outside of the scope of your question, though. You didn't define the `imagesa` property for us.

Comment: Sorry For that but now what is solution?

Comment: Solution to what, exactly? I have already provided you with the ability to sort your array *and* make it mutable again (in two different ways).

Answer (score 0):

You should set the pageLabel test based on your index variable (+1), not the pageNumber.  As follows:

```
[pageLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %lu",(long unsigned)(index+1)]];
```

Comment: then how about arrangement of my images? you not understand my question i want like as my JSON PageNumber1 image at First then PageNumber2 image and upto array index.

Comment: Hadn't spotted that they are out of sequence - go with Ian MCDonald's answer to sort by page_no.

Answer (score 0):

Bro you drop value in An array Like this

```
       if([imgDict count]>0)
          {
           NSMutableArray *imgsLinkArray = [imgDict objectForKey:@"demopage"];
           self.imagesa = imgsLinkArray;
          }
```

Then you have all the value in self.imagesa array....

So just wright only this....

```
 [pageLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %lu",(long unsigned)[[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"page_no"]]];
```

For your short array OrderBy ............

```
  NSMutableArray *recent=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"page_no" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)] ;
  [self.imagesa sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
  recent = [[self.imagesa sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]] copy];
  self.imagesa = (NSMutableArray *) [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:recent];
```